# Tesla coil tuning to space model

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, electric-circuits

How do I model space so I can tune my tesla coil to give the most RF output at a required resonant frequency? The coil runs at 1 MHz that in aerial terms is a very short aerial so I am effectively looking to generate photons at a point.

Answer (score 0):

Free space has a property called impedance, as does the wire(s) coming off the hot side of your tesla coil. For best transfer of power out of the coil and into the free space surrounding it you need to match the impedance of the coil to that of free space. This is accomplished using a thing called an antenna.

In its customary form, an antenna is a straight piece of wire, cut to a length of about 1/2 of the wavelength of the signal you wish to transmit. The wire is also cut through at its midpoint and the hot-side signal from the coil is fed into one side of the wire pair and the ground return of the coil is connected to the other.

A good impedance match requires that the length of the antenna be carefully adjusted for the specific frequency at which you wish to operate the coil. If the antenna is too long or too short, the impedance match will be poor and the antenna's radiation effectiveness will suffer significantly.

A simple device called an *SWR meter* is commonly used to measure the quality of the impedance match.

A more complicated device called an *antenna analyzer* is used to model the details of how radio frequency energy being fed into the antenna is propagated into space.

More details about this topic can be obtained by posting questions at the amateur radio stack exchange.